# How do I draw a line between 2 points in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, draw

I need to draw a line between 2 points within a View component. Is this something I should learn React Native ART for? What would be the easiest way to accomplish this in React Native?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the react-native SVG library.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#line

Comment: Yep I ended up figuring that out. Thanks!

Comment: How to make it responsive?, for example if there is two `image` and connected with a `line` then if I drag the image to XY positions then the line should move with that too.

Comment: @Muhammad did you found any solution for the same. I'm facing the same issue